# Comparing NSStrings before (and after) saving to sqlite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, sdk, nsstring

On my Mac and iPhone, using objective-c, I can save the EURO character to an sqlite database.

Before I store it, the length of the NSString is 1 (Or should that be 2?)

After I retrieve it back from the database, the length of NSString is now 2 (Or should that be 1?)

How do I compare those 2 NSStrings?    isEqualToString doesn't work.

(Reading/writing/comparing works fine as long as I stick to characters 0-127.)

This is a heavily trimmed-down sample of the sqlite READ code:

```
NSMutableString *s = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int i, numberOfColumns=0, columnType, numberOfRecords=0;
int anyInt;
double anyDouble;

char *anyText;

int prepareErrorNumber = sqlite3_prepare_v2(g_Db, [sqlCmd UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil);

if(prepareErrorNumber == SQLITE_OK)
{
    while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        numberOfRecords++;
        numberOfColumns = sqlite3_column_count(statement);

        columnType = sqlite3_column_type(statement, i);
            if(columnType == SQLITE_INTEGER) { anyInt    = sqlite3_column_int(statement, i);          [s appendFormat:@"%d", anyInt   ]; }
            if(columnType == SQLITE_TEXT   ) { anyText   = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i); [s appendFormat:@"%s", anyText  ]; }
            if(columnType == SQLITE_FLOAT  ) { anyDouble = sqlite3_column_double(statement, i);       [s appendFormat:@"%f", anyDouble]; }
        }

 ... etc...
```

Comment: Example code showing what exactly you do to store and load the string would be helpful.

Comment: Your code is handling encoding incorrectly. Post the relevant bits and we can help. :) In particular, we're interested in how you put the string into sqlite and how you get it back out.

Comment: I'll dig up the actual code.  (It's on my work computer.)   So you are saying I should *NEVER* get back 2 bytes... if I store 1?  (I thought sqlite *DID* do that if the character was outside the 0-127 range.  No?)  That fact that [dbResults length] is 2... definitely means my sqlite reading/writing code is wrong?)  I'm using some pretty standard sqlite code that appears all over the net... that always works for everything EXCEPT >127 characters.

Comment: So normally I *SHOULD* be able to see a length of 1 character (EURO) before (and after) I save/load from the database?  And isEqualToString should compare them just fine?

Comment: Keep in mind that an NSString's length is not the number of bytes, but instead the number of characters.  If it takes two bytes to convey one EURO character in NSString *mystring, [mystring length] will be one.  On the other hand, strlen([mystring UTF8String]) will be two.

Comment: I would probably use `[s appendString: [NSString stringWithUTF8String: ...]]` instead of `[s appendFormat:@"%s", ...]`, but I'm not convinced that's your problem. I think it's more likely your write code.

Comment: Oh, have you tried using the sqlite3 command line on your database yet? If the data is good in the database, it's your read code. If it's already corrupted (as I suspect will be the case), the problem is in how you've created the database. (Always cut problems into the smallest possible pieces!)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to add insert as an NSString and read as an UTF8String.

Use the instance method [UTF8String](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBHCCED) when writing and the class method [stringFromUTF8String:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBGJGID) when reading.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are creating the `NSString` using the information gathered from the read in the wrong way. Here is a complete example of writing a Euro sign to a database and then reading it back:

```
//clang -g so_sqlite3_nsstring.m -framework Foundation -lsqlite3 \
//    -o so_sqlite3_nsstring
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

#define DB_PATH "so_enc.db"

enum {
  ALL_OK,
  CANT_OPEN,
  CANT_CREATE,
  CANT_INSERT,
  CANT_FIND,
};

struct ExecCBCtx {
  NSString **out_string;
};
int ExecCB(void *ctx, int col_count, char *col_text[], char *col_name[]);

sqlite3 *DBCreate(void);
void DBWrite(sqlite3 *db, NSString *text);
NSString *DBRead(sqlite3 *db);

int
main(void) {
  id pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  sqlite3 *db = DBCreate();

  // Use universal character name for U+20AC "EURO SIGN".
  NSString *text = @"\u20AC";
  DBWrite(db, text);

  NSString *text2 = DBRead(db);
  (void)sqlite3_close(db);

  BOOL eq = [text isEqualToString:text2];
  NSLog(@"%@ = %@? %s", text, text2, eq? "YES" : "NO");
  [pool drain];
  return ALL_OK;
}

void
DBOpen(sqlite3 **out_db)
{
  sqlite3 *db = NULL;
  int rc = sqlite3_open(DB_PATH, out_db);
  if (rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "sqlite3_open: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(*out_db));
    (void)sqlite3_close(*out_db);
    exit(CANT_OPEN);
  }
}

sqlite3 *
DBCreate(void)
{
  sqlite3 *db = NULL;
  DBOpen(&db);

  static const char CREATE_TABLE[] =
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"TEST\" (\"STRING\" char(9))";
  char *errmsg = NULL;
  int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, CREATE_TABLE, ExecCB, NULL, &errmsg);
  if (rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", __func__, errmsg);
    sqlite3_free(errmsg);
    (void)sqlite3_close(db);
    exit(CANT_CREATE);
  }
  return db;
}

void
DBWrite(sqlite3 *db, NSString *text)
{
  static NSString *const WRITE_TABLE_FMT =
      @"INSERT INTO \"TEST\" VALUES (\"%@\")";
  NSString *writeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:WRITE_TABLE_FMT, text];
  const char *cmd = [writeText UTF8String];

  char *errmsg = NULL;
  int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, cmd, ExecCB, NULL, &errmsg);
  if (rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", __func__, errmsg);
    sqlite3_free(errmsg);
    (void)sqlite3_close(db);
    exit(CANT_INSERT);
  }
}

NSString *
DBRead(sqlite3 *db)
{
  static const char READ_TABLE[] =
      "SELECT * FROM \"TEST\"";

  NSString *text = nil;
  struct ExecCBCtx ctx = {&text};

  char *errmsg = NULL;
  int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, READ_TABLE, ExecCB, &ctx, &errmsg);
  if (rc && rc != SQLITE_ABORT) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", __func__, errmsg);
    sqlite3_free(errmsg);
    (void)sqlite3_close(db);
    exit(CANT_FIND);
  }
  sqlite3_free(errmsg);
  return text;
}

int
ExecCB(void *ctx, int col_count, char *col_text[], char *col_name[])
{
  //fprintf(stderr, "%s: %p - %d cols - %s - %s\n",
  //        __func__, ctx, col_count, col_text[0], col_name[0]);
  if (!ctx) return 0;

  struct ExecCBCtx *out = ctx;
  NSString **text = out->out_string;
  if (*text) return 1;

  *text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:col_text[0]];
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output from a sample run:

```
2010-11-17 14:34:05.436 so_sqlite3_nsstring[23536:903] € = €? YES
```

Answer (score 0):

> => Use the instance method UTF8String when writing

Done.  (I didn't show that code, but it was already being done.)

> => and the class method stringFromUTF8String: when reading.

I assume this is the line that I need to fix.
But what would it look like?
I can't get stringFromUTF8String to work, no matter how I re-write it.

```
if(columnType == SQLITE_TEXT   ) 
{ 
    anyText = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i); 
   [s appendFormat:@"%s", anyText]; 
}
```